# setState blocks editing of TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, validation, onchange, setstate, texteditingcontroller

I am using a `TextFormField` as a widget and `TextEditingController` inside TextFormField for a phone number, and I am trying to validate a number while typing with the `flutter_libphonenumber` library, which provides an async function for validation.
I am trying to change the colour of the text depending upon validation status while entering it.

**Current state:**

1. Implemented `TextFormField` and providing it `TextEditingController` as a controller with valid **initial text**.
2. Implemented `onFieldSubmitted` and it works fine on tap of Done button of the keyboard.
3. Added `listener` to this controller for validation and set _isValid bool there.
4. I have used this bool to set colour of text inside the controller while building it.
5. So the current issue is, when I am entering text I get proper validated status inside the listener, but the colour of text is not changing accordingly.

I understand this is happening due to not calling `setState` after validation, so it will rebuild the widget and change the colour according to _isValid.

**Error:** When I try to `setState` inside the `listener`, it just doesn't allow editing.

**Note:** I have tried the same approach using `onChanged` method and it also does same, cannot enter or delete anything inside textField if there is pre-populated text (`initialText`).

Can anyone help me to solve this issue, or guide the correct path?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form widget's autovalidate field by doing

```
Form(
 autovalidate: true
```

Comment: Tried `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` it also doesn’t allow editing if it has any valid initial text.